# Is uploading a file to my bucket with a name that already exists a good practice in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-storage

So I'm currently building an application that gives users the ability to create a profile that includes a profile picture, they can update the profile picture which components use to render an image in a couple of places, I initially set up a cloud function that listens for this update operations and updates it in a lot of places where it is referenced, a drawback to this was that I would have to perform a lot of write operations in my firebase firestore and couldn't update the fields in some places as it would cost me a lot to have to perform read operations on a lot of data in several locations, I wanted to prevent duplication of data by reading such data from a central location that is updated alone as opposed to all these locations, but that requires performing a lot of read operations each time this data is needed. I later decided to have a name that each users profile picture will have even if they upload a new file it'll have the same name as their previously uploaded file this solves the issue with all the read and write operations.

I have a couple of questions about this:

1. Is this a good practice.
2. If no why?
3. Does firebase replace the previous file with the new file or it just does a search and returns the first file it finds with the requested filename, what happens?

Comment: I store user profile images with path `profile/{user_uid}` in firebase storage, it saves us a lot of space since when a user upload picture either it creates a file (1st time) or rewrites the uploaded image on the same file (from 2nd time). I consider it a good practice.

Comment: I think you're making an assumption *it just does a search and returns the first file*, as Firebase doesn't search - you have to write code to perform searches. More importantly, you cannot have duplicate filenames so if you store a file at path */images/my_image.jpg* and then store another file at */images/my_image.jpg* it will always overwrite it. In fact it works exactly the same way the database does - you cannot have duplicate documentId's (keys) in the same collection. Because of that, the question is a bit unclear - what are you asking?

Comment: @Jay your comment answered my question thank you

Comment: @p2pdops that's an ingenious means of storing their info, I think I'll adopt that, thanks :)